# Sum of hours within two times

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

I am trying to find a formula in Excel to calculate the total of hours worked that fall between 6am and 8pm.

For example:

Start Time 04:00 End Time 22:00 = 14hr

Start Time 10:30 End Time 21:00 = 9.5hr

Start Time 00:00 End Time 23:59:59 = 14hr (Rounded. 23:59:59 used to designate midnight).

Start Time 00:00 End Time 12:00 = 6hr

Note that the formula does not need to calculate across multiple days. Each day is in a separate row.

I have found the below formula (not sure if it is the best for this situation) which picks up the end time within 8pm, but don't understand the formula enough to include the minimum start time of 6am.

=(MAX(0,MIN(E15,INT(E15)+20/24)-MAX(D15,INT(E15)))+IF(DAY(D15)<>DAY(E15),MAX(0,MIN(E15,INT(D15)+20/24)-MAX(D15,INT(D15)))))*24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If start time is in A2 and end time is in B2, and if there are no periods spanning midnight, you can use

```
=MIN(TIME(20,0,0),B2-INT(B2))-MAX(TIME(6,0,0),A2-INT(A2))
```

Format the result with custom format `[h]:mm`

[image]